# Configure route to handle /Controller/Action/0000-00000-0000-0000

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How to configure route so it allows syntax like this:

```
/ControllerName/ActionName/0000-00000-0000-0000
```

Where last part is Guid?

```
public ActionResult ActionName(Guid value){}
```

Comment: See this article that has the solution: http://0hlsson.se/2012/06/18/asp-net-mvc3-routing-with-guid/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a custom route definition. The last parameter is a route constraint in the form of a regular expression that requires `value` to match the Guid format.

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "YourRouteName",
  "{controller}/{action}/{value}", 
  new { controller = "ControllerName", action = "ActionName" },
  new { value = @"^(\{{0,1}([0-9a-fA-F]){8}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){12}\}{0,1})$" }
);
```

Comment: Here's where I got the Guid regex: http://madskristensen.net/post/validate-a-guid-in-c

Comment: Do we need a custom route for Getting GUID as a parameter? I dont think so right. Can you check out my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add some new routing. You'll want to do something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "MoveToTab",
    "{controller}/{action}/{value}",
    new { controller = "ControllerName", action = "ActionName",
        value = System.Guid.Empty }
);
```

Here the `ControllerName` and `ActionName` would be the defaults for those sections.